# Filter the data by date and time (HH:MM:SS) and aggregate the data into rows of 5-minute intervals per month in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, split, aggregate

**Problem**

I have a very large data frame (almost 20,000 rows) where data was documented approximately every 1-3 minutes. Unfortunately, I am unable to upload any authentic data to this post.

**Aim**

The aim is to reduce the size of the data frame by filtering the rows by date and time into 5-minute intervals for each month. The data spans over 4 years.

I have tried using different packages and functions in **R** to figure out how to do this over the last couple of days to no avail such as **dplyr(), aggregate(), and tidyverse()**, and I just can't solve this conundrum.

**Structure of the data frame**

**I have a data frame like this**

```
ID    Date       Time    
 1 9/15/16 6:48:00 AM 
 2 9/15/16 6:54:00 AM 
 3 9/15/16 6:57:00 AM 
 4 9/15/16 6:59:00 AM 
 5 9/15/16 7:03:00 AM 
 6 9/15/16 7:05:00 AM
```

**I would like to convert this data into a data frame like the example below by calculating the number of minutes and seconds between each subsequent 'ID' row.**

```
    ID    Date Start_Time    End_Time Minutes Seconds
     1 9/15/16 6:48:00 AM  6:54:00 AM     5.0  300.00
     2 9/15/16 6:54:00 AM  6:57:00 AM     3.0  180.00
     3 9/15/16 6:57:00 AM  6:59:00 AM     2.0  120.00
     4 9/15/16 6:59:00 AM  7:03:00 AM     4.0  240.00
     5 9/15/16 7:03:00 AM  7:05:00 AM     2.0  120.00
     6 9/15/16 7:05:00 AM  etc
```

**Afterwards, I'd like to filter the data frame containing the new calculations between the subsequent rows of **'IDs'** by date and time into 5-minute or 300.0-second time intervals per month to reduce the size of the data frame.**

The output should be something like this unless someone has a more efficient method.

```
    ID    Date Start_Time    End_Time Minutes Seconds
     1 9/15/16 6:48:00 AM  6:54:00 AM     5.0  300.00
```

I appreciate your thoughts on this

Many thanks in advance.

**Progress**

Many many thanks in advance for this solution, it worked really well. Sorry for all these questions, I am a novice with R. Could I please query what the warning message below means (**ℹ  232 failed to parse**) and what went wrong with the calculations of minutes and seconds for the rows in my data frame(**' New_Track'** - see below)? The minutes and seconds are exactly the same in all columns called 'Minutes' and 'Seconds'. In addition, for IDs 7 and 8, the new calculations show the difference is 950520 minutes and seconds when the correct calculation is approximately 2 minutes or 120 seconds (see below).

**Row 7**

```
7     7  9/15/16  7:07:00 AM 2016-09-15 07:07:00 2016-09-26 07:09:00  950520M 0S  950520
8     8  9/26/16  7:09:00 AM 2016-09-26 07:09:00 2016-09-26 07:11:00     120M 0S     120
```

**Warning Message:**

```
##My data frame is called 'track' and the columns are: (1) ID; (2) Date; and (3) Time

##Code:

New_Track <- data.frame(
+                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
+                       ID = track$ID,
+                       Date = track$Date,
+                       Time = track$Time
+                        ) %>%
+                             mutate(Start_Time = mdy_hms(paste(Date, Time)),
+                             End_Time = lead(Start_Time),
+                             Minutes = minutes(End_Time-Start_Time),
+                             Seconds = (End_Time-Start_Time) / dseconds(1))
Warning message:
Problem while computing `Start_Time = mdy_hms(paste(Date, Time))`.
ℹ  232 failed to parse.
```

**New Data frame Layout - 'New_Track'**

```
  ID     Date        Time          Start_Time            End_Time     Minutes Seconds
1     1  9/15/16  6:48:00 AM 2016-09-15 06:48:00 2016-09-15 06:54:00     360M 0S     360
2     2  9/15/16  6:54:00 AM 2016-09-15 06:54:00 2016-09-15 06:57:00     180M 0S     180
3     3  9/15/16  6:57:00 AM 2016-09-15 06:57:00 2016-09-15 06:59:00     120M 0S     120
4     4  9/15/16  6:59:00 AM 2016-09-15 06:59:00 2016-09-15 07:03:00     240M 0S     240
5     5  9/15/16  7:03:00 AM 2016-09-15 07:03:00 2016-09-15 07:05:00     120M 0S     120
6     6  9/15/16  7:05:00 AM 2016-09-15 07:05:00 2016-09-15 07:07:00     120M 0S     120
7     7  9/15/16  7:07:00 AM 2016-09-15 07:07:00 2016-09-26 07:09:00  950520M 0S  950520
8     8  9/26/16  7:09:00 AM 2016-09-26 07:09:00 2016-09-26 07:11:00     120M 0S     120
9     9  9/26/16  7:11:00 AM 2016-09-26 07:11:00 2016-09-26 07:13:00     120M 0S     120
```

Comment: You can use something like: `cut(x, breaks="5 min")` to divide you dataset into 5 minute intervals, then summarize the intervals with the dplyr package.

Comment: Thanks, Dave2e. I have just researched the parameters for cut(). Would x be combined vectors: x = c(ID, Date, Time), then Breaks<-cut(x, breaks="5 min"). If you can expand on your answer, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L),
              Date = c("9/15/16","9/15/16","9/15/16",
                       "9/15/16","9/15/16","9/15/16"),
              Time = c("6:48:00","6:54:00","6:57:00",
                       "6:59:00","7:03:00","7:05:00")
) %>%
  mutate(Start_Time = mdy_hms(paste(Date, Time)),
         End_Time = lead(Start_Time),
         Minutes = minutes(End_Time-Start_Time),
         Seconds = (End_Time-Start_Time) / dseconds(1))
```

Result

```
  ID    Date    Time          Start_Time            End_Time Minutes Seconds
1  1 9/15/16 6:48:00 2016-09-15 06:48:00 2016-09-15 06:54:00   6M 0S     360
2  2 9/15/16 6:54:00 2016-09-15 06:54:00 2016-09-15 06:57:00   3M 0S     180
3  3 9/15/16 6:57:00 2016-09-15 06:57:00 2016-09-15 06:59:00   2M 0S     120
4  4 9/15/16 6:59:00 2016-09-15 06:59:00 2016-09-15 07:03:00   4M 0S     240
5  5 9/15/16 7:03:00 2016-09-15 07:03:00 2016-09-15 07:05:00   2M 0S     120
6  6 9/15/16 7:05:00 2016-09-15 07:05:00                <NA>    <NA>      NA
```

It's still unclear to me what you're looking for for this:

> I'd like to filter the data frame containing the new calculations
> between the subsequent rows of 'IDs' by date and time into 5-minute or
> 300.0-second time intervals per month to reduce the size of the data frame.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is a boat track line and I will be plotting it on a map in QGIS. Coordinates (longitude and latitude, date, and time) of the boat were taken every 1-3 minutes. So the analysis is less intensive, Therefore, I would like to plot point data every five minutes instead of every 1-to 3 minutes. I thought this method decreased the size of my data frame. If you have any better suggestions, I would happily receive them.

Comment: I inputted my code from your solution above and I was wondering if I could please query a warning message and the calculation for IDs 7 and 8. Many thanks in advance for helping with my understanding

Comment: 1) It will be much easier to help if you share sample data in a reproducible way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.  `dput()` is often the quickest way.  2) It sounds like 232 of your 20k rows have inconsistent date or time formatting, you can use `resultant_data_frame %>% filter(is.na(Start_Time))` to see what those rows look like. 3) Your row 8 is 11 days later, not 2 minutes later.  4) I think your "thin the data" question should be a separate question. You might filter to keep only rows where enough time or distance has changed.